# How can I repair a large chip in the front of a concrete hearth?

Tags: concrete, fireplace, hearth

I am working on an old fireplace and there seems to be some damage to the hearth.

The middle section has some damage on the face and I'm wondering how to go about repairing it. They are made from concrete it appears and have a distressed face edge.

Here is what it looks like from the top.

[image: broken hearth from top]

Here is an image from the front.
[image: front view]

And here is how it is supposed to look.
[image: undamaged hearth]

Is this fixable?
If so, can anyone give me some direction on how to go about fixing it.

I would prefer to patch it and match the existing pieces as best as possible without covering it or adding any sort of nosing.

Comment: I don't think you can make a patch that doesn't look like a patch.   Perhaps tiling the hearth would be the simplest solution and even improve the look.

Comment: Do you have the pieces?

Comment: @isherwood Yes, the fireplace is at my brothers house.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have the pieces, that's where I'd start. Use wood glue, project adhesive, or epoxy to reinstall them. Take care to not leave any exposed adhesive, as it won't easily be removed. Use masking tape to secure the parts while the glue dries.

Then, use some concrete repair material with a sandy texture to very precisely fill any gaps to smooth things out.

This will get you closest to a decent patch. You'll retain the proper color and texture over most of it. Any other approach will just draw the eye to the repair.

Comment: I didn't think to use epoxy. Hopefully it goes back together smoothly.

Comment: I've done some repairs of faux stone on a fireplace using wood glue. Worked very well, and water cleanup.

Answer (score 1):

**You could cover it with a metal stair nosing.**

[image: stair nosing]

[source](https://www.lowes.com/pd/M-D-1-28-in-x-96-in-Pewter-Stair-Edging/50065921?cm_mmc=shp-_-c-_-prd-_-flr-_-ggl-_-LIA_FLR_244_Tools-Setting-Materials-Access-_-50065921-_-0-_-0-_-0&ds_rl=1286981&gclid=CjwKCAjwiY6MBhBqEiwARFSCPts0Bj4tOD4n-eNL7LzmaH70q8HptYJyr0jUZQYkAExnsdnFSLvdNxoCJagQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds)

They come in all kinds of colors.  If you could find one that was similar to the metal of the fireplace it would echo that and be a good look.  You would glue it down to the concrete lip and cover that divot.  It would also protect the concrete edge from taking more damage.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I would prefer to patch it rather than cover it. I'll edit my question to clarify.